# BLE Swift code is scanning but not finding BLE devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In Swift, and Xcode 9, I am trying to scan for and connect to all BLE devices. This code should print out "no name" for all BLE devices found. Scanning is working, but my BLE devices are not being found. Beside me, there is an Android phone with BLE, which I am unable to find. 
Simulation device: iPhone 6s, bluetooth turned -ON

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

//let  svcLight = CBUUID.itit(string: "24958294582945")

class BLEViewController: UIViewController , CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        //scan for peripherals if "on" state change
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn{
            //not concerned with any services for now, and we are not passing in any options
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
            print("scanning...")
            //check for other states, add if else statements
        }
    }

    //handle the callback for when something is found
    //diddiscover was the autocomplete word for a peripheral
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        if peripheral.name?.contains("POR 1007BT") == true {
        //even if the peripheral doesn't have a name, we will get some info for it
            print (peripheral.name ?? "no name")
            centralManager.stopScan()
            print(advertisementData)
            //connect to the peripheral now
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            //store a local copy of the peripheral in the property
            myPeripheral = peripheral
    }
}
    //so our central can begin scanning again
    //if peripheral disconnects for whatever reason, it will immidiately start scanning
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }

    //callback for connecting to a central, didconnect was the autocomplete word
    //discovr services
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("connected \(peripheral.name)")
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        peripheral.delegate = self

    }

    //callback for diddiscover services: auto complete: diddiscover
    //for each of the services in my peripheral, print out the UUID
    //may not need this funciton, need to check

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        //optionally binding it
        if let services  = peripheral.services {
            for svc in services {
                print(svc.uuid.uuidString)
            }
        }
    }


    //! is used to unwrap it so anywhere in the code, it doesn't need to be unwrapped as an optional
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    //keep a reference/store our peripheral
    var myPeripheral : CBPeripheral?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   //create instance of CBManager
        //pass in self as the delegate to handle any callbacks
        centralManager = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil)


    }
```

Comment: Do you see the device with `LightBlue.app`? Also "This code should print out "no name" for all BLE devices found" this is contradicting with your code, because if you pass the test `if peripheral.name?.contains()`, then `peripheral.name` should exists, no? "there is an Android phone with BLE, which I am unable to find" But is that device advertising? Because if not, you won't find it.

Comment: @Larme You were spot on with all your comments. The LightBlue app is awesome- Thanks for the great recommendation. For some reason my android phone wasn't detected as a peripheral with LightBlue, so I just switched to another active peripheral nearby, and it connected! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @Larme i tried LightBlue and BlueCap apps but no one can find my printer in searching. what should we do now ?

Comment: @iNiravKotecha Are you sure your Printer is `BLE` and not classic Bluetooth? Does it need to user interaction to be advertising? If you use Settings.app/Bluetooth, do you see it?

Comment: @Larme i think printer is not BLE. then how can we connect ?